# How do we enable/Disable App slicing feature of iOS 9

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, app-thinning

AS iOS 9 is supporting App slicing feature just by adding needed images to image assets and you will get sliced app when download from appstore.

1) My question is do we need to do extra steps for App slicing feature or by just adding image to image assets it will work on Appstore (not like we are checking bitcode feature at the time of upload)

2) How can i deactivate App slicing feature even if i am using image assets.

Comment: Why would you want to disable app slicing? It's no work to you and it's better for the user.

Comment: I know rmaddy, i am asking because if my image assets is not having valid images(consider i don't have images for 4s and i am installing it in 4s) then what will happen ?

Comment: The 4s requires 2x images like nearly every device. If you don't have 2x images then you don't have images for every other device except for the iPad 2 (needs 1x images) or the iPhone 6+/6s+ (needs 3x images).

Answer (score 3):

1) No. You are right as per apple doc it clearly states [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html)

2) I think we can not disable it.

Trying to answer your comment:

**Theoretically:-** i think if you some how forget to provide @....x image, still app store process will provide an alternative image to specific device. It may be same as @3x/@2x/@1x (what ever developer have provided ). If developer have provided more than 1 image like @1x and @3x both then @3x will be download to all device except @1x supported device.

**Practically:-**

- Delete @1x or @2x what ever you want from image.xcasset.
- Create archive.
- Export the app for the target device to get ipa.
- Change the .ipa extension to .zip and unpack the archive.
- You should be able to see what images are there @1x/@2x/@3x. These
  are the images which user will be downloading for his device.

Comment: so i don't need to do anything right ? If yes then consider if my image assets is not having valid images(consider i don't have images for 4s and i am installing it in 4s) then what will happen ?

Comment: I'd like to mention that "Export the app for the target device to get ipa." step is quite useful in order to *get a clue* what goes to the end user after app slicing. I said *get a clue* because the final slicing performed by iTunes, which might use different logic then Xcode does.